# Handle null >= 0 in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, logical-operators

I have a simple check where I want to check if the given variable is >=0.

```
public print(value: any): void {
    if(value >= 0) {
      console.log('Greater than zero')
    }
  }
```

The catch here is when the incoming variable has value null, then it will become truthy and log the statement. Is there a clean way to avoid it, but not adding extra checks?

Comment: What's wrong with an extra check? `if(value !== null && value >= 0) {`

Comment: I get a lint warning for using "null" in my code and the build fails. It suggests to make use of "undefined" I do not want to suppress the lint warning that's why looking for alternate ways.

Comment: `Number(null)` evaluates to `0` so any slick tricks won't apply

Comment: yes expected type for value is number. But that too will not solve the problem.

Comment: There is `if(value?.valueOf() >= 0)` if you want your coworkers to throw stationery in your direction.

Comment: lol :D @adiga better go with long way by adding extra checks

Comment: How about `if (typeof value === 'number' && value >= 0)` for the check?

Comment: Thank you all of you for your inputs. I think adding null check is the best one and more understandable :D

Comment: just use `parseInt` check if not NaN and don't bother

Comment: Thank you @JózefPodlecki that's quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) that will assure the compiler that you're not handling a `null` but a number. Moreover, it will make the code more *correct*, since with `value: any` this means you might get a boolean or a string passed in:

```
public print(value: any): void {
  if (typeof value === "number") {
    //value is definitely a number and not null
    if (value >= 0) {
      console.log('Greater than zero')
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa0AOArgEYgCWw+ATqQHYAuAFAG5ggECmAXNGDfAJTcmAe1IATdNly5SAM2gM68PO2HyWbdtAC8u6ACIaBALZF2lff0k5puAPR2NHaKRhj2s2qTrsQ8HtBGpuY8NBI0wnSBBCAgUrYu8syszgB82tAADFaYNgnQwMI0EMIg7AB0IMIA5gwA5ADilOxgPpTQdAAWvNAAXubCdfzxtgC+I9DjNlNT2IXFUQAeOoHsAO5wSCgQDPwA3NjYi+V41PQMACwATPtHJ2eMRrG3WMentIz6nb5Vlgev9w+DFkrAg7BeQA)

Now the code specifically verifies that you do get a number and then checks if it's more than or equal to zero. This means that a `null` or a non-number value would not be processed.

The type guard condition can be combined with the other for brevity:

```
public print(value: any): void {
  if (typeof value === "number" && value >= 0) {
    console.log('Greater than zero')
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa0AOArgEYgCWw+ATqQHYAuAFAG5ggECmAXNGDfAJTcmAe1IATdNly5SAM2gM68PO2HyWbdtAC8u6ACIaBALZF2lfdABkV6Bo7QAfNugAGfpJzTcwYTQjCIOwAdCDCAOYMAOQA4pTsYHTm0HQAFrzQAF7mwlH8UtIAvgXFWKXYvv500AAeOtA07ADucEgoEAz8ANzY2DXBeNT0DAAsAEzdfQNDjEYgIJNY-YO0jPqp7PPC+ovLMwyyrBDs3UA)

Or extracted on its own to just reduce the nesting:

```
public print(value: any): void {
  if (typeof value !== "number")
    return;

  //value is definitely a number and not null
  if (value >= 0) {
    console.log('Greater than zero')
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa0AOArgEYgCWw+ATqQHYAuAFAG5ggECmAXNGDfAJTcmAe1IATdNly5SAM2gM68PO2HyWbdtACEAXl3QARDQIBbIu0qH+U6bkrs6BSjQDc2W7gD0XjR2ikMGLssrSkdOwg8DzQJuaWPDQSNMJ0sQQgIJ4B8sys-gB8BgAM-JI4dtDAwjQQwiDsAHQgwgDmDADkAOIOYBGU0HQAFrzQAF6Wwh02FbgAvrYLWEvY1bVpAB7QBjTsAO5wSCgQDPzuWNgbjXjU9AwALABMZ5fXt4wmmS9YVze0jIYhpEWtZzr93gxZKwIOwzkA)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you don't want to add a null-check.

An alternative is to use `number` instead of `any` but it will work only if your `ts.conf` enables strict null checks.

```js
function print(value: number): void {
    if(value >= 0) {
      console.log('Greater than zero')
    }
}

print(null) // won't compile with strict null checks
```

Answer (score 1):

If you codebase does not allow the use of `null`, just use `undefined` and use an implicit conversion, like so:

```
public print(value: any): void {
    if(value != undefined && value >= 0) {
        console.log('Greater than zero')
    }
}
```

This works because `null == undefined` (the double equals creates a type conversion, while the triple equals does not).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, I usually use the following:

```
`${value}` >= 0

// or

parseInt(value) >= 0
```

in TypeScript you can most likely use:

```
public print(value: any): void {
  if (+`${value}` >= 0) {
    console.log('Not less than zero')
  }
}
```